# WCF communication across domains

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow WCF service (ServiceDMZ) that is installed on a server across the firewall.  This service is running under a Windows account on that server.  Account name: DMZDomain\DMZUserName.

I have another workflow WCF service that is running on my development machine (ServiceDev).  This is a self hosted service running under my Windows account: DevDomain\DevUserName.

ServiceDev communicates with ServiceDMZ using wsHttpContextBinding and context correlation in the Send and Recieve activities.  ServiceDMZ uses a callback address to communicate back to ServiceDev when it is done completing a task.

I get this error in the Send activity of ServiceDev:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed. at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target) at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.ThrowIfFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target) at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.ServiceModel.Activities.InternalSendMessage.OnSendFailure(NativeActivityFaultContext context, Exception propagatedException, ActivityInstance propagatedFrom) at System.Activities.Runtime.FaultCallbackWrapper.Invoke(NativeActivityFaultContext faultContext, Exception propagatedException, ActivityInstance propagatedFrom) at System.Activities.Runtime.FaultCallbackWrapper.FaultWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

What should the settings be in the app.config file for ServiceDev and ServiceDMZ?

Thanks!

Hello, thanks for the comments. Here are the configuration files.

**ServiceDev**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="ServiceDev" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceDevBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://10.204.78.16:9101/"/>
      </baseAddresses>          
    </host>
    <endpoint address="http://10.204.78.16:9101/ServiceDev" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IServiceDev" bindingConfiguration="ServiceDevBinding"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="http://10.204.78.16:9101/ServiceDev/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="http://10.204.78.16:9101/ServiceDevCallback" binding="wsHttpContextBinding" contract="IServiceDevCallback" bindingConfiguration="ClientServiceDMZBinding"></endpoint>        
  </service>
</services>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://10.169.24.14:9100/ServiceDMZ" binding="wsHttpContextBinding" contract="IServiceDMZ" name="ClientServiceDMZ" bindingConfiguration="ClientServiceDMZBinding">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="DMZUserName@dmzsvr1.mysite.com"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceDevBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="8388608">
      <security>
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="TripleDesRsa15" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpContextBinding>
    <binding name="ClientServiceDMZBinding" clientCallbackAddress="http://10.204.78.16:9101/ServiceDevCallback">
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpContextBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceDevBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <sqlWorkflowInstanceStore connectionStringName="MySite.Deployment.Data.Providers.WorkflowInstanceStoreProvider" instanceCompletionAction="DeleteNothing" instanceLockedExceptionAction="BasicRetry" instanceEncodingOption="GZip" hostLockRenewalPeriod="00:01:00"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<standardEndpoints>
  <dynamicEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="ClientServiceDMZDynamicEndpointConfiguration">
      <discoveryClientSettings>
        <endpoint kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint" endpointConfiguration="ServiceDMZUDPDiscoveryEndpoint"></endpoint>
      </discoveryClientSettings>
    </standardEndpoint>
  </dynamicEndpoint>
  <udpDiscoveryEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="ServiceDMZUDPDiscoveryEndpoint" discoveryVersion="WSDiscovery11">
    </standardEndpoint>
  </udpDiscoveryEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<diagnostics performanceCounters="All">
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="30000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000000">
  </messageLogging>
</diagnostics>
```

**ServiceDMZ**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="ServiceDMZ" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceDMZBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://10.169.24.14:9100/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="http://10.169.24.14:9100/ServiceDMZ" binding="wsHttpContextBinding" contract="IServiceDMZ" bindingConfiguration="ServiceDMZBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceDMZEndpointBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="http://10.169.24.14:9100/ServiceDMZ/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    <endpoint name="udpDiscovery" kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpContextBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceDMZBinding" clientCallbackAddress="http://10.204.78.16:9101/ServiceDevCallback">
      <security>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" realm="" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpContextBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceDMZBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDiscovery>
        <announcementEndpoints>
          <endpoint kind="udpAnnouncementEndpoint" />
        </announcementEndpoints>
      </serviceDiscovery>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceDMZEndpointBehavior">
      <endpointDiscovery>
        <scopes>

        </scopes>
      </endpointDiscovery>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<standardEndpoints>
  <udpDiscoveryEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="ServiceDMZUDPDiscoveryEndpoint" discoveryVersion="WSDiscovery11" maxResponseDelay="00:00:00.600"/>
  </udpDiscoveryEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>

<diagnostics performanceCounters="All">
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="30000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000000">        
  </messageLogging>
</diagnostics>
```

Comment: What authentication scheme and security settings are you using? Can you post your configurations?

Answer (score 0):

This could be is a partial trust problem. Security is WCF requires full trust for full functionality, without this it only supports a subset of the functionality, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412186.aspx

Also if you are using windows authentication it would require trust between the domains, assuming that your machines are in different domains.